# Есть смысл использовать Next.js на стороннем сервере?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Ребята, приветствую. Сейчас рассматриваем вариант перенести react-приложение созданное на основе create-react-app на Next.js. Для хостинга не планируем использовать Vercel. Посдкажите нормально будет работать собранное приложение , если не использовать для хостинга Vercel ? в таком случае есть вообще смысл связываться с Next.js ?) раньше не работал с этим фреймворком , поэтому возникают вопросы ) Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Не проблема. Просто разворачиваете приложение на вашем сервере, чаще всего над запущенным сервером ноды через next.js стоит nginx.
Примерная реализация.

1. Подтягиваете весь проект на сервак через гит
2. Делаем билд
3. Запускаем через start (по дефолту).
4. Запускается сервак на ноде с проектом (localhost:3000 если по дефолту)
5. Через nginx проксируете локалхост на нужным домен и все работает.
   Для того чтобы процесс ноды не падал после выхода из сервера, используется pm2 (читайте документацию).
   Надеюсь я понял вопрос правильно и ответил на него

Comment: А можно подробно описать про nginx?

Comment: Я не бэк разработчик, но у меня на проекте поверх он стоит как и у других моих коллег. Это сложилось больше исторически, нежели по прихоти или необходимости. Nginx просто добавляет дополнительные плюшки (редиректы на стороне не нодовского сервера и прочие его возможности. С учетом моего скудного опыта девопса - он не обязателен)